# Field variables in Typescript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript

I'm getting into Typescript, and I can't seem to figure out the structure of classes exactly. 
Namely how to use field variables.

```
class NumberClass {
    private numberArray1: number[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    public numberArray2: number[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    numberArray3: number[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var numberArray4: number[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];


    validateNumber(): void{

        for (var i: number = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
            //validate numbers
        }
    }

}
```

`numberArray1` to `numberArray3` says that it cannot be resolved, 
`numberarray4` breaks absolutely everything and tells me that a constructor, method, accessor or property is expected.

Can anyone tell me what it is that I fail to understand? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have couple of problems in your code.

You cannot have loose variable declared as part of the class definitions. Only private/public/protected or nothing is allowed. No access modifier is the same as public. Therefore your #1,2,3 are valid. But #4 is not.

If you want to access instance field in your class method your should use 'this' keyword:

```
 for (var i: number = 0; i < this.numberArray1.length; i++) {
         //validate numbers
 }
```

Or declare this field as static:

```
private static numberArray1: number[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

And access it through class name:

```
for (var i: number = 0; i < NumberClass.numberArray1.length; i++) {
        //validate numbers
}
```

Comment: Ah, it seems that I have to use "this" a lot more than I'm used to. 
Thanks a lot! I wanted it to be private, and it works with the "this" keyword.